# MythTV could not connect to the database

Tags: mythtv

I have downloaded the backend and front end of mythtv for 14.04 but when I open up the backend to configure I get a screen to select country then on the next page I get: MythTV could not connect to the database. Please verify your database settings below. Required fields are marked with and asterisk (*).

*Hostname: localhost
[/]Ping test server?    Port:3306
Database name: mythconverg
User: mythtv
Password: mythtv

All of that was already filled out, I haven't changed anything.  The only answer I have found to this issue is for mythbuntu located [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2072687&page=4).

Comment: Are you sure mysql is running? try running:
 
     "sudo status mysql"

from a terminal

Comment: I entered that and got: mysql start/running, process 1126
I tried going back into mythtv backend and it still did the same thing.

Comment: Do you create a password during the mySQL install. I've notice a problem whenever I try anything other then a carriage return (CR) as the default password.

Comment: I am not sure what MySQL is but it shows its installed.  I don't know how to edit the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to reinstall MySQL and enter "mythtv" as the password there as well.  All other posts showed to leave the password blank in MySQL but that did not work.  [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MythTV/Install/Troubleshooting#head-75ded5e7682340f0a88f9ed6ec69a68b6a8b4162) is the resource page I used to fix the problem.

Comment: More here: https://forum.mythtv.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=201

Answer (score 4):

I found the correct password (which was randomized) in `/etc/mythtv/config.xml` and entered this in the `Password:` field of the MythTV setup screen.  This solved the problem for me. `mythtv` was not the correct password.  This issue may be Ubuntu/Debian-specific.

Comment: I don't think anything has ever been more surprisingly difficult than trying to set up *any* decent TV-watching application under Ubuntu/Linux.

Comment: I finally got MythTV up and running (at least the basic functionality) with my [HDHomeRun Connect](https://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Silicondust_HDHomeRun_Dual) with the help of [this ~30 minute video walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNWXg39qQH8).

Comment: Had to use `mythfrontend --geometry 1920x1080+0+0` (replace the first `0` with a horizontal position) to control which monitor MythTV displays on.

Comment: Fix aspect ratio under `Setup->Appearance`.  It apparently couldn't determine the display aspect ratio on my system and defaulted to `4:3`.  This caused it to scale the HD image on one axis for reasons I haven't yet comprehended.

Comment: There are some other interesting options under `Setup->Appearance`.  For example, you can uncheck `Hide mouse cursor in MythTV` which was a default feature that was contributing to my annoyance.

Comment: Note that the menu sequences will be different depending on your selection for `Setup->Appearance->Menu theme`, so you may have to hunt around to find the relevant configuration pages.

Comment: As an example of the complexities in getting a TV tuner working with MythTV is that when you run `mythtv-setup` to configure the backend, you need to set the "Capture card", the "Video source", *and* you must connect the two under "Input connections".  So you aren't going to figure this out without following some instructions.